# Falling back to loading/storing access token from NSUserDefaults because of simulator bug

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When I am running my application in iphoneXS(simulator) and iphoneXSMax(simulator) at the time of loading my application I am getting an error called Thread found nil while an optional value but in console:

> Falling back to storing/loading access token in NSUserDefaults because of simulator bug getting this error.

I am getting exception only in iphoneXS(simulator) and iphoneXSMax(simulator) and all other simulators are working good.

I am using Xcode 10 and swift4

Please help me to get rid of this

Comment: Can you share the code what you have tried. It will help to debug the issue.

Comment: Yaa, but code please